# Pandas: why pandas.Series.std() is quite different from numpy.std()

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I got two snippets code as follows.

```
import numpy
numpy.std([766897346, 766897346, 766897346, 766897346, 766897346, 766897346, 766897346, 766897346, 766897346, 766897346])
0
```

and

```
import pandas as pd
pd.Series([766897346, 766897346, 766897346, 766897346, 766897346, 766897346, 766897346, 766897346, 766897346, 766897346]).std(ddof=0)
10.119288512538814
```

That's a huge difference.

May I ask why?

Comment: This looks like a bug in pandas to me can you post an [issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues)?

Comment: Already reported and answered here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/10489

Comment: From the discussion in the issue: a possible solution until it is fixed is to ensure you have bottleneck installed.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is indeed already under discussion ([link](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/10242)); problem seems to be the algorithm for calculating the standard deviation which is used by `pandas` since it is not as numerically stable as the one used by `numpy`.

An easy workaround would be to apply `.values` to the series first and then apply `std` to these values; in this case `numpy's` `std` is used:

```
pd.Series([766897346, 766897346, 766897346, 766897346, 766897346, 766897346, 766897346, 766897346, 766897346, 766897346]).values.std()
```

which gives you the expected value 0.

Comment: I have noticed the algorithm difference before. Here, I do not think it is the cause. If you want to get the result '0', the numerator should be '0'. So no matter numpy or pandas, the result should be the same, '0', since their difference is only about the denominator. So I think here it is a bug.

Comment: It is a bug, I agree. That's why I posted the link to the thread where it is discussed and presented the work-around. What else did you expect from an answer to this question which you would accept? :) The bug is based on the algorithm which is used (variance and standard deviation are closely connected).

Comment: I do not think the bug relates to the algorithm. For numpy, the std is unbiased by 1/n. For pandas, the std is biased by 1/(n - 1). That's the difference of their algorithm. So here, the result from pandas is 0. For this interesting 0, no matter which algorithm, they should be the same. Can you see it? Because if A * 1 / (n - 1) = 0, then A * 1 / n = 0. So I guess there might be some stupid bug in there but I am sorry I have no time to trace. Anyway, thanks a lot for your kind help.